# Lines from Oracle Spatial Layer in QGIS are not completly visible

Tags: qgis, line, oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

I connected a spatial layer from the Oracle database which contains lines (OracleDB objectclass typ is polyline) to be visible in QGIS.

An example geometry is as follows:

```
sdo_geometry(2002,2056,null,
    sdo_elem_info_array(1,4,3,1,2,1,7,2,2,11,2,1),
    sdo_ordinate_array(2610857.31245004,1266613.32122543,2610857.70740207,1266610.23735626,2610858.72627747,1266602.3016907,2610859.88613344,1266593.26306758,2610859.84612155,1266592.56309404,2610859.5561095,1266591.92511322,2610859.27210097,1266591.49512447))
```

In QGIS only a part of the above line is visible. I know that this line is not only straight. So I was wondering, if there is kind of an "arc-problem" behind this and if there is any known solution to the problem?

I didn't find anything in the official QGIS documentation.

Comment: Which qgis version?

Comment: I checked it using Oracle 12c and QGIS 3.4.1 and I get a straight line with an arc at its end, see https://imgur.com/a/6JeLHHY
Is this the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working with the QGIS 2.18.24 long term release, when the problem occured. Using the new QGIS 3.4.1 version, the line is perfectly visible.